# How should I know the return type of an object in jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, forms

I have a form. I am using validation and after that I submit a form..

```
var flag=$("#form1").validate();
```

The above code returns an object. I want to check that if the above code is validate, then submit a form using jquery ajax. How I can do that?

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/anish/Q9qes/9/

Thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery validate function allows you to define a submit handler - that's where you'd fire off the AJAX. You should be passing validate() an object with your specifics. See http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation for documentation. Quick example...

```
$('#form1').validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    // Do your ajax here.
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The `validate()` function just sets up/initialises the form to be validated, this needs to be called when the page is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Tell jQuery that this form should be validated
    $("#form1").validate();
});
```

If you want to check whether a form is validated when you click a button you need to do

```
$("#form1").valid();
```

which will validate form and prevent it submitting if the form doesn't validate, however, clicking the form's submit buttons will run that `valid()` function anyway, and display errors if the form isn't valid.

Comment: it's an object type.so i can't get the boolean value

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I forgot the `valid()` function validates the form without returning a boolean output, but it does prevent the form from submitting if the form doesn't validate. Will update the code.